# Do I correctly understand difference between 'could hardly [v]' and 'hardly [v2]'

Tags: meaning, understanding

example:

- he spoke very quickly, so I could hardly understand him. - **(I
  understood (0-25%) of all)**
- he spoke very quickly, so I hardly understood him. - **(it was hard,
  but I did(understood) it (75%-100%) of all)**

**Is it right in this context?**

and one another question: is it correct to replace **understood** with **did** in the top section?

Comment: I see no justification for assigning percentage probabilities here. Both phrasings imply the speaker *did* understand, albeit with difficulty. It's a matter of opinion whether anybody thinks either version implies more difficulty and / or less understanding than the other. And you can't just replace ***understood*** with ***did*** - they're completely different verbs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I used percent because my existing knowledge of English is not so good. I haven't had an alternative yet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so what about this definition for do. 'used to avoid repeating a verb or verb phrase:' from 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/'.

Comment: It's a pointless question. A native speaker probably wouldn't get themselves tied up knots with ***hardly*** *(minimally)* and ***hard*** *(laborious)*. It's too reminiscent of *"How's the job? Working hard, or hardly working?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers maybe the question I have created is wrong. I try to understand the difference between 'could [v]' and [v2]. Are they interchangeable?

Comment: @FumbleFingers.Could you look at the bottom answer? That is what I mean by under the percent.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. It's *possible* to "deconstruct" your two alternative phrasings as if they mean different things. #1=almost unable, #2=limited success. Which *in theory* implies that speaker understood 100% in #1 (with difficulty), whereas in #2 he might only have understood a tiny fraction of what was said. But in practice a pointless distinction, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He spoke very quickly, so I could hardly understand him.
MEANS
He spoke very quicly so I **was almost not able** to understand him.

VERSUS
He spoke very quickly, so I hardly understood him.

The sentence above is the usual way to use hardly.

hardly means barely. If you barely or hardly understand someone, you have difficulty in understanding them. But you are able to understand them.